# Expression to hide tablix in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I wish to set the visibility for the tablix based upon the value selected in parameter.

The scenario is I have four tablix week, month, quarter, year. I have created a parameter "timeline" and in the parameter i have added week month quarter year as specified values in available values option

I have used the following queries but i cant hide those tablix if I select corresponding value from the timeline parameter (Even if I select or deselect any value in the parameter all the four tablix are displaying)

**=IIF(Parameters!Timeline.Value = "Month",TRUE,FALSE)**
**=IIF(Parameters!TimeLine.Label.Equals("Year"),True,False)**

What expression would fix this issue?

[Here is the screenshot of the Report screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKKSz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code by following below note:

Set visibility false of all your tablix so that when you will select all

```
=SWITCH
(Parameters!Timeline.Value = "week",TRUE,FALSE,
Parameters!Timeline.Value = "month",TRUE,FALSE,
Parameters!Timeline.Value = "quarter",TRUE,FALSE,
Parameters!Timeline.Value = "year",TRUE,FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the Visbility on the Column Group. (MTD, QTD, YTD, etc) and not on the Taxlib itself.

Additionally, for the MTD for example, the hidden expression `Parameters!Timeline.Value <> "Month"`

Hope this helps.